# help and verification of 3 short exercises

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, self-learning

I'm reading an old book and find the following three question. I'd like to know two things: if my attempts are correct and also it would be great if someone could give suggestions in more detail. Thank in advance

(1) Let $f: \mathbb{N} \backslash\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{N} \backslash\{0\}$ be an injective function. Then the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \prod_{k=1}^n f(k)$$

Converges or diverges?

My attempt: (**Please someone could help me with this** $\prod_{k=1}^n k\ge n!$ I know which is correct but I'm not sure of how prove it.)

$$\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod_{k=1}^n k\le \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod_{k=1}^n f(k)$$

Hence by comparison test the series diverges.

(2) Let $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $f_m(x)=x^3+3x+m$. Show that $f_m$ cannot have more than two roots if it is restricted to $[0,1]$.

Suppose for sake of contradiction that it has two different roots $a<b \in [0,1]$. Let $c\in (a,b)$. Since in the domain the function is strictly monotonic increasing. Then $f(a)<f(c)$ and $f(c)<f(b)$. But $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Contradiction.

(It can be shown that $f(x)$ is strictly monotonic increasing using the laws of exponentiation. In particular, $a,b\ge 0, r\ge 0$, and $a<b$ then $a^r<b^r$)

(3) Let define the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2,& x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
0,& x\in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}  \end{cases}$$

Let $g(h)=f(h)/h$ when $h\not= 0$. Show that $g(h)\rightarrow 0$ when $h\rightarrow 0$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. We set $\delta=\varepsilon$. So for $0<|x|\le \delta$ we have  to show that $|f(x)/x|\le \varepsilon$. If $x$ is irrational the result is trivial. If $x$ is rational (clearly is not zero) then $|f(x)/x|=|x^2/x|=|x|\le \varepsilon$.

Any suggestion it would be great.

In (2) none of the $n$ really affect nothing right?

Comment: It's wrong for the first one that $f(k)\ge k$. For example $f(2)=1,f(1)=2,f(3)=3,f(4)=4,\dotsc$. It's true that $f(1)\dotsb f(k)\ge k!$ by the injectivity of $f$.

Comment: I see, so how could I proof this inequality rigorously?

Comment: For (2), the "Rolle's Theorem"-type argument is applicable _somewhere_ because $ \ f_m' \ $ is always positive.  But by itself, it doesn't address the matter of the interval being specified as $ \ [ 0, 1 ] \ . $

Comment: But this exercise is before Rolle's theorem.

Comment: The largest one of $n$ distinct positive integers is no smaller than $n$. It could be proved by pigeonhole principle.

Comment: That may be as far as the book is concerned; I'm just saying that your argument uses similar reasoning.  What are $ \ f(0) \ \text{and} \ f(1) \ $ and how many intercepts could there be in $ \ [0,1] \ $ for various values of $ \ m \ $?  (Or does $ \ m \ $ even matter?)

Comment: I think in this case $m$ doesn't do a difference.

Comment: @JoseAntonio Can you tell us what "old book" these are from? Thanks!

Comment: Yes the book is "Calculus" and was made by the math department of my university (university of guadalajara), I don't know the date in which were published but considering the state of the book might have about 20 years or even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:  I would choose $f(k) = k+1$, which is clearly injective; for if $f(a) = f(b)$, then $a+1 = b+1$, hence $a = b$.  Then $$\prod_{k=1}^n f(k) = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n+1) = (n+1)!,$$ hence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \prod_{k=1}^n f(k) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1,$$ which is trivially divergent.  In fact, the more interesting question is this:  for *any* injective $f$ on the positive integers to the positive integers, is the given sum *necessarily* divergent?

Question 2:  Suppose $0 \le a < b \le 1$ such that $f_m(a) = f_m(b) = 0$.  Then $$a^3 + 3a + m = b^3 + 3b + m = 0,$$ or equivalently, $0 = (b-a)(b^2 + ba + a^2 + 3)$.  Since $b > a$, it follows that $b^2 + ba + a^2 + 3 = 0$, but this is obviously impossible if $a, b$ are nonnegative.  Indeed, the given conditions are much more strict than is necessary:  $m$ need not be integer, and the roots need not be bounded above by $1$.  In fact, the roots need not be bounded below by $0$, either, but to prove this is a tiny bit more difficult.

Question 3:  Your proof is essentially correct as written.

Comment: After all, thanks for your help. With respect to Q1) to show that this holds for any injective map from the positive integer to the positive integer, the clue is to show that $f(1)...f(n)\ge n!$. For this I'm not completely sure, but maybe an argument by contradiction works.

Comment: Suppose that $n> f(i)$ for all $i\le n$. Then  $n-1$ is an upper bound for the sequence $(f(i))_{i=0}^n$. So $\{f(i):1\le i\le n\} \subset \{1\dots n-1 \}$. So $\{1\ldots n\}\xrightarrow{f}\{f(i):1\le i\le n\} \hookrightarrow\{1\ldots(n-1) \}$ is an injection from a set of $n$ elements to a set with $n-1$ elements contradicting the pigeon-hole principle.  Then for all $n$ there is a $0\le i\le n$ such that $f(i)\ge n$. Then the assertion follows.

Comment: For (2) also the arguments of showing that is strictly monotonic increasing I think works. But is much more easily to follow your argument. Thanks =)